# Can I switch back and forth between original campaign and The Following in Dying Light?

Tags: dying-light, dying-light-the-following

I've read that there is no way to move between original city and The Following map in Dying Light in-game - you have to select map you are going to play from start menu.

So,
1) Can I use single character to play one campaign and then switch to another (yes, I am thinking of starting Following, getting crossbow and getting back to original campaign). Will I keep a crossbow in that case?

I don't own The Following at the moment so I can't try it myself and couldn't find the answer in Google.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to my question in [this interview](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/dying-light-the-following-everything-you-need-to-k/1100-6434385/).

> "Yes, you will be able to transfer your character and progress from the main campaign to Dying Light: The Following and vice versa. You can then develop that character further in both the main game and the expansion."

So yep. Crossbow, I'm going for you!

Comment: Did you confirm this by trying it yourself?

Answer (score -3):

If you mean transferring from the DLC map and the normal campaign map just by walking and climbing, the no, it isn't possible. The only way to actually move Kyle from The Following map and the campaign is via the home menu.

Comment: This doesn't add anything not said years ago.